# GLIBC_2.29 can not be found for avrdude even after downloading it

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, glibc, fhs

I have a bit of a struggle with using `avrdude` to **flash** my microcontroller.

It dependends of `libm.so.6` **GLIBC_2.29** which it cannot find. It looks under `/usr/lib/libm.so.6` where this file does actually resides BUT it also resides in `/lib/lib.so.6`.

So as I was running

```
sudo pacman -S glibc
```

to install/update the library https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/glibc/

I am very sure I installed it only to `/lib/`.

But since `avrdude` is looking into `/usr/lib` it still won't find it. I have a hard time to understand the sense of these two directories since it kinda screws up things than helps for my case.

How can I do it properly?

**EDIT**

I wanted to do something stupid so I did `cp /lib/libm.so.6 /usr/lib/libm.o.6` but the `cp` command tells me the files are the same.

Now I do not understand why `avrdude` can not find the right version of GLIBC since it is updated properly (as far as I can see that).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654603/how-to-install-latest-glibc-version-2-29-beside-system-installed-one-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that the installed `glibc` is an incomplete `C runtime.`
>   In order to complete the `C runtime` you may need to copy in
>   additional headers that match the compiler you are using since the use
>   of `--sysroot` will restrict their lookup to the `sysroot`.

It is very possible to have multiple versions of glibc on the same system (we do that every day).

However, you need to know that glibc consists of many pieces (200+ shared libraries) which all must match. One of the pieces is ld-linux.so.2, and it must match libc.so.6, or you'll see the errors you are seeing.

The absolute path to ld-linux.so.2 is hard-coded into the executable at link time, and can not be easily changed after the link is done.

To build an executable that will work with the new glibc, do this:

```
g++ main.o -o myapp ... \
   -Wl,--rpath=/path/to/newglibc \
   -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2
```

The `-rpath` linker option will make the runtime loader search for libraries in `/path/to/newglibc` (so you wouldn't have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running it), and the `-dynamic-linker` option will "bake" path to correct `ld-linux.so.2` into the application.

If you can't relink the `myapp` application (e.g. because it is a third-party binary), not all is lost, but it gets trickier. One solution is to set a proper `chroot` environment for it. Another possibility is to use [rtldi](http://bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi.html) and a [binary editor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_editor)

### **SOLUTION #1**

```
LD_PRELOAD='mylibc.so anotherlib.so' program
```

### **Solution #2**

### **compile your own glibc without dedicated GCC and use it**

This setup might work and is quick as it does not recompile the whole GCC toolchain, just glibc.

But it is not reliable as it uses host C runtime objects such as `crt1.o,` `crti.o`, and `crtn.o` provided by glibc. This is mentioned at: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location Those objects do early setup that glibc relies on, so I wouldn't be surprised if things crashed in wonderful and awesomely subtle ways.

For a more reliable setup, see Setup 2 below.

Build `glibc` and install locally:

```
export glibc_install="$(pwd)/glibc/build/install"

git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout glibc-2.28
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix "$glibc_install"
make -j `nproc`
make install -j `nproc`
```

### **Setup 1: verify the build**

test_glibc.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

atomic_int acnt;
int cnt;

int f(void* thr_data) {
    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
        ++cnt;
        ++acnt;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Basic library version check. */
    printf("gnu_get_libc_version() = %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());

    /* Exercise thrd_create from -pthread,
     * which is not present in glibc 2.27 in Ubuntu 18.04.
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291 */
    thrd_t thr[10];
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_create(&thr[n], f, NULL);
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_join(thr[n], NULL);
    printf("The atomic counter is %u\n", acnt);
    printf("The non-atomic counter is %u\n", cnt);
}
```

Compile and run with `test_glibc.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
gcc \
  -L "${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -I "${glibc_install}/include" \
  -Wl,--rpath="${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="${glibc_install}/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
  -std=c11 \
  -o test_glibc.out \
  -v \
  test_glibc.c \
  -pthread \
;
ldd ./test_glibc.out
./test_glibc.out
```

The program outputs the expected:

```
gnu_get_libc_version() = 2.28
The atomic counter is 10000
The non-atomic counter is 8674
```

Command adapted from https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location but --sysroot made it fail with:

```
cannot find /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libc.so.6 inside /home/ciro/glibc/build/install
```

so I removed it.

ldd output confirms that the ldd and libraries that we've just built are actually being used as expected:

```
+ ldd test_glibc.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4bfd3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc12ed92000)
        libc.so.6 => /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc12e9dc000)
        /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc12f1b3000)
```

The gcc compilation debug output shows that my host runtime objects were used, which is bad as mentioned previously, but I don't know how to work around it, e.g. it contains:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

### **Setup 1: modify glibc**

Now let's modify glibc with:

```
diff --git a/nptl/thrd_create.c b/nptl/thrd_create.c
index 113ba0d93e..b00f088abb 100644
--- a/nptl/thrd_create.c
+++ b/nptl/thrd_create.c
@@ -16,11 +16,14 @@
    License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
    <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

+#include <stdio.h>
+
 #include "thrd_priv.h"

 int
 thrd_create (thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg)
 {
+  puts("hacked");
   _Static_assert (sizeof (thr) == sizeof (pthread_t),
                   "sizeof (thr) != sizeof (pthread_t)");
```

Then recompile and re-install glibc, and recompile and re-run our program:

```
cd glibc/build
make -j `nproc`
make -j `nproc` install
./test_glibc.sh
```

and we see hacked printed a few times as expected.

This further confirms that we actually used the glibc that we compiled and not the host one.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229

[https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recallrev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location)